# Unable to update the EntitySet 'EmpresasModulos' because it has a DefiningQuery and no <InsertFunction> element exists

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transacciones

Estoy haciendo un alta de empresas, mediante una transacción. La transacción tiene dos partes, la que se guarda los datos de la empresa, y la que guarda IDs de modulos en otra tabla.

La primera parte que guarda los datos de las empresas funciona bien, cuando quiero guardar los IDs de los modulos me salta un error:

"Unable to update the EntitySet 'EmpresasModulos' because it has a DefiningQuery and no  element exists in the  element to support the current operation.Unable to update the EntitySet 'EmpresasModulos' because it has a DefiningQuery and no  element exists in the  element to support the current operation."

Los modulos se guardan en la tabla llamada "EmpresasModulos", los datos de empresas se guardan en la tabla "Empresas".

Los modulos son guardados dentro de un `string`, y luego uso  `.split(',')` para que se me transforme en `string[]` y asi recorrerlos uno por uno e ir guardandolos dentro del objeto "empresasModulos" durante la transacción.

Éste es mi código donde hago la transacción:

```
       [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AltaParametros(string ModulosActivos, string valoresParametros string BtnFinish)
        {
            string modulosActivos = null;
            string ValoresParametros = null;
            Empresas empresasObj = null;
            string[] modulos = null;
            string[] arrayParams = null;
            int[] myInts = null;


            try
            {
                modulosActivos = Session["modulosActivos"] as string;
                arrayParams = modulosActivos.Split(',');
                myInts = arrayParams.Select(int.Parse).ToArray();

                ValoresParametros = GetParametros(valoresParametros);
                empresasObj = GetEmpresas();

                if(BtnFinish != null)
                {
                    using (DbContextTransaction dbTran = qavant.Database.BeginTransaction())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Empresas empresa = new Empresas()
                            {
                                Nombre = empresasObj.Nombre,                                
                                Nemonico = empresasObj.Nemonico,
                                LogoUrl = empresasObj.LogoUrl,
                                DireccionApp = empresasObj.DireccionApp,
                                DireccionWeb = empresasObj.DireccionWeb,
                                Habilitada = empresasObj.Habilitada,
                                TipoValidacionId = 1,                                
                            };

                            qavant.Empresas.Add(empresa);
                            qavant.SaveChanges();

                            for(int i = 0; i < arrayParams.Length; i++)
                            {
                                EmpresasModulos empresasModulos = new EmpresasModulos()
                                {
                                    EmpresaId = empresa.Id,
                                    ModuloId = myInts[i]
                                };

                                qavant.EmpresasModulos.Add(empresasModulos);
                            }

                            qavant.SaveChanges();
                            dbTran.Commit();
                            
                            RemoveDatos();
                            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Empresas");
                            
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            dbTran.Rollback();

                            ViewBag.Title = "Ups, tuvimos un error al dar de alta la empresa...";
                            ViewBag.Description = "Error al dar de alta la empresa...";
                            ViewBag.VerError = ex.Message + "\b" + ex.InnerException.Message;

                            return View("Error");
                        }
                    }
                }

                return View();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return View("Error");
            }
        }
```

El problema es dentro del for(), lo recorre pero tira ese error mencionado

Comment: Ya investigaste el error? La entidad está mapeada a una Query? La entidad está mapeada a una Vista? La entidad está mapeada a una tabla que **no tiene primary key**?

Comment: La entidad está mapeada a una tabla que no tiene primary key, pero sí son Foreign Keys, no tiene Primary key porque la columna "EmpresaId" se va a repetir varias veces (exactamente la cantidad de modulos que le esté pasando), es decir, si es la empresa con ID 1, y le paso 10 modulos, en la columna "EmpresaId" va a tener diez 1, uno por cada modulo

Comment: El hecho que EmpresaId se repita, no tiene nada que ver. Si la tabla EmpresaModulo guarda la relación entre una empresa y un módulo, entonces, debe haber un ModuloId. Y si existe ModuloId, es probable que exista la tabla Modulo. Y si ambas son verdad, entonces tienes una tabla intermedia. Y no hay nada que prohiba tener una llave compuesta [IdEmpresa,IdModulo]. La otra opción es decirle a EF que la tabla EmpresaModulo **no tiene primary key**

Comment: Claro, yo tengo tres tablas, "Empresas", "Modulos", "EmpresasModulos", "EmpresasModulos" tiene las PK de "Empresas" y de "Modulos", y los datos que quiero guardar van en la tabla intermedia "EmpresasModulos". Cómo le digo a EF que no tiene Primary Key?

Comment: *Cómo le digo a EF que no tiene Primary Key?* esa es otra pregunta. Ya investigaste? Además, la relación entre módulo y empresa sólo puede existir una vez, correcto? Esa tabla podría tener tres campos: `IdEmpresaModulo`, `ModuloId`, `EmpresaId`. Por qué no haces `IdEmpresaModulo` la llave primaria?

Comment: Si, investigue pero no encontré algo que me funcionara. Lo que pasa es que lo que tengo en la tabla intermediaria son datos que se van repitiendo. Una empresa puede tener muchos modulos, y un modulo puede estar en muchas empresas.

Comment: Cuales son las tablas que se relacionan con EmpresaModulos(seria buena que pusieras esta estructura en tu pregunta)

Comment: Solo la tabla "Empresas" y la tabla "Modulos" se relacion con "EmpresasModulos"